# regex restrict string

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have requirement to restrict a string using regex in angular. I used ^(?!.*Test).*$ but the issue is that it restrict all the string starting with word Test i.e if i type Test1 , testimony it fails. Validation shall only restrict Test word. It shall work as :

1) Test - not allowed

2) test- not allowed

3) Test123 - Allowed

4) Testimony - Allowed

How do we do it regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need word boundary

```js
let test1 = "Test";
let test2 = "test";
let test3 = "Testsdfsdf";

let regex = /^Test\b/i;

console.log(regex.test(test1));
console.log(regex.test(test2));
console.log(regex.test(test3));
```

Comment: Thanks Aftab but its not working with ng pattern. do i need to change regex for ng-pattern?

Comment: Not used it. You can still use plain JS regex right? Don't use ng-pattern

Comment: okay..Thanks for your help